# Why do I get different alignment when using \selectlanguage in the second coffin rather than \foreignlanguage (TL 2017)?

Tags: vertical-alignment, babel, languages, expl3, welsh

Why do I get the different alignment in the following example when I use `\selectlanguage`, as opposed to using `\foreignlanguage`? There was a spacing issue due to a Babel bug in TeX Live 2016. However, that was fixed in TeX Live 2017, so I assume this is a different problem.

I assume I could replicate this using `minipage`s rather than `coffin`s. However, my initial attempts to do this were unsuccessful, so here's the `coffin` version, which at least simplifies checking for the introduction of spurious spaces!

```
\documentclass[welsh,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel,expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_prawf_prif_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin
\vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_prawf_prif_coffin { \textwidth }
{
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { \textwidth }
  {
    \mbox{}
  }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpb_coffin { .5\textwidth - .5\columnsep }
  {
    A~rainbow:~red,~orange,~yellow,~green,~blue~\dots
    \skip_vertical:n \medskipamount
    \par
  }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { .5\textwidth - .5\columnsep }
  {
    {
      \selectlanguage{welsh}
      Enfys:~coch,~oren,~melyn,~gwyrdd,~glas~\dots
    }
    \skip_vertical:n \medskipamount
    \par
  }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { T } { r } \l_tmpa_coffin { T } { r } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { T } { l } \l_tmpb_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}
\coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_prawf_prif_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
\par

\vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_prawf_prif_coffin { \textwidth }
{
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { \textwidth }
  {
    \mbox{}
  }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpb_coffin { .5\textwidth - .5\columnsep }
  {
    A~rainbow:~red,~orange,~yellow,~green,~blue~\dots
    \skip_vertical:n \medskipamount
    \par
  }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { .5\textwidth - .5\columnsep }
  {
    \foreignlanguage{welsh}
    {
      Enfys:~coch,~oren,~melyn,~gwyrdd,~glas~\dots
    }
    \skip_vertical:n \medskipamount
    \par
  }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { T } { r } \l_tmpa_coffin { T } { r } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { T } { l } \l_tmpb_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_prawf_tmpa_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}
\coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_prawf_prif_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned rainbows]

Comment: For `\selectlanguage` the manual states »If used inside braces there might be some non-local changes«.  I guess that is the culprit.  When using `\tracingall` the log is about 2000 lines longer when I use `\selectlanguage` :/   I guess the breaking change will be hard to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the specials that `\selectlanguage` inserts. It is meant to switch the 'entire' language so adds to the `toc`, *etc.*:

```
...........\write1{\select@language{welsh}}
...........\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{welsh}}}
...........\write1{\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{welsh}}}
...........\write1{\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{welsh}}}
```

(from `\showoutput`). On the other hand, `\foreignlanguage` doesn't do this: it's for 'local' changes only. That makes a difference as the `\write` node at the start of the box means that we can't 'see' the baseline of the first row of text: the `\write` node is the reference point and it comes at the top of the text.

This is a 'known issue' in TeX, most obviously with colour specials. The LaTeX3 `xgalley` approach can solve it by carefully managing all such operations, but it currently doesn't 'play nicely' with the vast majority of LaTeX2e packages. So for the present you will need to use avoid such switches right at the top of boxes.

Comment: Thanks. I knew colour switches could do strange things, but I didn't make any connection with this. Is there any way I can compensate for the space within the coffin? Or when joining the coffins?  I don't care about the ToC etc. in this particular case, but I do want something like `\XXXname` to be switched.

Comment: I have to say that LaTeX is a complete pain for bilingual stuff!

Comment: @cfr [Come to the dark side...](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/language)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Not an option, I'm afraid. Curious if you say it works in ConTeXt, but wouldn't help, even if I already knew how to use ConTeXt. ConTeXt is far too KOMA-like for this.

Comment: @HenriMenke Where does ConTeXt store its language files?

Comment: @HenriMenke Does it even support Welsh? There doesn't seem to be any code for any of the Celtic languages in `lang-def.mkiv`, for example. Just a comment line in between the Baltic set and CJK.

Comment: @cfr Welsh might be too exotic.  Hyphenation patterns are stored in the [`patterns` folder](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/tex/context/patterns/mkiv).

Comment: @HenriMenke It doesn't give an error. It just ignores the switch. If I'm in English, it keeps using US punctuation. If French, French punctuation. (Just looking at the quotation marks from the example.) I assume there's a way of getting British, but that's not much help. I need Welsh and British. And it doesn't seem exotic to me - very homely, in fact.

Comment: @HenriMenke It has hyphenation patterns, but I wouldn't trust them. The list of characters given is wrong. `ŵ` and `ŷ` are crucial. But those aren't even listed as characters. (I don't know if TeX's are any better. But it is not encouraging.)

Comment: @cfr `This file is part of the hyph-utf8 package.`  ConTeXt only converts LaTeX patterns to Lua.  Does `babel` have own patterns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62491/discussion-between-cfr-and-henri-menke).

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure if you want perhaps just to change the hyphenation language rather than using the entire `babel` mechanism: if you just want a box of 'some text' hyphenated correctly then this would be fine. That doesn't involve a `\write` so will work.

Comment: @JosephWright What I've actually done is align the coffins at the baseline rather than the top, which happens to work. I could also use `\foreignlanguage` here, but a bit less conveniently. But I'd rather, of course, have a more general solution.

Comment: Is there a better way of remembering this? Can I make a macro output a warning if used at the top of a box? Something like make `\cymraeg` use `\selectlanguage` but warn if at the top of a box/coffin. I keep forgetting this and thinking I must be doing something screwy with poles or baselines or somesuch.

Comment: Also, could you clarify the suggestion about hyphenation patterns? It would do for bilingual syllabus headings, probably. (Probably would do for the whole thing, but theoretically I mean to get things like `\contentsname` to do something bilingual when I have time. (I don't mean change `\contentsname`, but get my ToC to include it twice, for example.)) Sorry, I know this is late for follow-up queries - can ask a new question if better.

Answer (score 1):

In ConTeXt local language switches work nicely with frames (ConTeXt equivalent of coffins).  Unfortunately, there are no language settings for Welsh.  Here is an example with English and German.

I chose the column width such that overfull boxes show up once you remove `\language[de]`.

```
\definefontfeature
  [default][default]
  [
    protrusion=quality,
    expansion=quality,
  ]

\starttext

\dontleavehmode
\startframed[location=top,width=.46\textwidth,align={justified,hz,hanging}]
  \language[en]%
  \input knuth
\stopframed
\hskip.08\textwidth
\startframed[location=top,width=.46\textwidth,align={justified,hz,hanging}]
  \language[de]%
  \blank[-line]% Compensate the blank line in aesop-de
  \input aesop-de
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you say it has no hyphenation patterns? As I say, I wouldn't trust them, but the file is there. I doubt it has much else, but I don't know how to do `\today` in ConTeXt, so I can't test.

Comment: @cfr `\currentdate`.  I thought there were no pattern.  I corrected my post.

Comment: Thanks. (+1) Not of any use to me, unfortunately, but may be of help to somebody else. To be honest, ConTeXt wouldn't solve the problem for me anyway, not in a general way, but it is a shame it doesn't provide settings for any of the Celtic languages. (Very surprised about this: would expect Irish Gaelic¸ at least.)

Comment: @cfr One reason is that ConTeXt has way fewer users than LaTeX and there probably hasn't been any demand for Celtic languages so far.  Also I'm pretty sure that Hans doesn't speak Irish Gaelic, so he will wait for a user to submit updated core files.

Comment: Not speaking Welsh didn't stop the authors of the files for `babel`, `polyglossia` and `datetime`, of course. This was obvious from the things which got typeset if you were foolhardy enough to ask for Welsh. (Standard `datetime` and `datetime2` still do this, as they can't be updated, but `babel` and `polyglossia` are fixed. At least, certainly much more fixed than they were.) But I take your point.

Comment: @HenriMenke Do you know if this also affects lists (TOC, _etc._) or only the box itself? LuaTeX certainly offers ways to store data which don't need a `\write` but a quick look at the tracing suggests that `\language` perhaps doesn't do quite the same scope of stuff as the `babel` `\selectlanguage`.